# Can I export an already existing docker container into a dockerfile?

Tags: docker

I may have not followed best practices, I believe, and I am kinda trying to correct myself

I have created a container starting from the Rust docker image for a project. I have been using this container more like a small VM rather than a container. Through the docker dashboard I start it every morning and work on it, either by `docker -it exec my-container bash` or using `docker exec` from scripts.
Since I created it from the Rust image, I have added users, installed crates and packages etc.

**Is there a way to create a Dockerfile from an existing docker container, that will contain all this, so I can use it to create ephemeral copies of this container to run specific jobs?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't. Since Docker doesn't keep track of your executed commands in interactive mode, it cannot generate a Dockerfile with your history. What you can do, though, is use [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) to save your changes as an image, or [`docker export`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/) to save your container as a tarball which can be later transformed in an image with the [`docker import`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/import/) command. The whole process follows:

- Get the `CONTAINER ID` from the container you wish to export with the `docker ps` command.
- If you wish to export the container:

  - Export you container with `$ docker export CONTAINERID > img.tar`
  - Import the container as an image with `$ docker import img.tar my-new-image:latest`
- If you wish to only save your changes as a new image:

  - Run `$ docker commit CONTAINERID my-new-image:latest`

Answer (score 0):

```
docker export [OPTIONS] CONTAINER
```

It'll export a container’s filesystem as a tar archive.

***Note***: The `docker export` command does not export the contents of volumes associated with the container. If a volume is mounted on top of an existing directory in the container, docker export will export the contents of the underlying directory, not the contents of the volume.

1. `sudo docker ps -aqf "name=containername"` or `docker inspect --format="{{.Id}}" container_name`
2. `$ docker export CONTAINERID > <your_exported_image>.tar`
3. `$ docker import <your_exported_image>.tar your-new-image:latest`
4. `$ docker commit CONTAINERID your-new-image:latest`

Comment: thanks I read this page in the manual but I didn't think it applied to my case. Are you saying though, that with command 3 I can create an image I can then deploy in multiple new containers?.
Also excuse my lack of knowledge on docker, but is command 4 then to update the image with possible future changes I do in one container? Meaning, could I just commit to the Rust image, avoiding all the other steps?